# WEIRD issue with xib file compared to screen output

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am working on a project and had zero problems up to now. This is my 9th VC and all of a sudden I am getting this weird output (see images). I have tried deleting the entire VC and creating a new one (twice) but same issue comes up.

I have only default code in .h and .m file right now. I have added no code myself.

What's going on here and why are the labels not lining up?

[screenshot from iPhone http://www.bahamapost.com/Stack_1.png](http://www.bahamapost.com/Stack_1.png)
[xib layout http://www.bahamapost.com/Stack_2.png](http://www.bahamapost.com/Stack_2.png)

Comment: Are you talking about the gap between Label5 and Label7?

Comment: Yes I am. In the xib there's a big gap but on the output screen there is no gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have fixed position of Label7 and Label8 from bottom or top. Open Size Inspector and select Label7, you'll see a bold red line at bottom and/or top in Autosizing grid. Click on that bold red line, it'll become dotted line. Repeat same for Label8.

Hope this fixes you problem :)

Comment: I looked at that and all labels have dotted lines (top left) in the size inspector.

Comment: Hey Atif, you kinda got me thinking on the right track so I'll give you the answer credit here. I resolved the problem by going to the File Inspector and deselecting the Use Autolayout function.